# Como colocar imagens em RSS em noticias?

Tags: javascript, rss

Atualmente estou trabalhando como programador Freelance com muita pouca experiência, então o cliente solicitou para coloca na pagina dele um bloco de noticias da UOL, então acidentalmente encontrei esse site.

[Free RSS Widget](http://www.surfing-waves.com/feed.htm)

Aqui você criar o bloco de notícias automaticamente via Javascript, veja como fica na pagina!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que o cliente solicitou que as noticias pudessem aparecer junto com imagens ou imagem.

Tem como fazer inserir imagens dinâmicas no **RSS**?

Esse é o código em Javascript:

```
<!-- start sw-rss-feed code --> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- 
rssfeed_url = new Array(); 
rssfeed_url[0]="http://feeds.folha.uol.com.br/mundo/rss091.xml";  
rssfeed_frame_width="200"; 
rssfeed_frame_height="260"; 
rssfeed_scroll="on"; 
rssfeed_scroll_step="6"; 
rssfeed_scroll_bar="off"; 
rssfeed_target="_blank"; 
rssfeed_font_size="12"; 
rssfeed_font_face=""; 
rssfeed_border="on"; 
rssfeed_css_url=""; 
rssfeed_title="on"; 
rssfeed_title_name=""; 
rssfeed_title_bgcolor="#3366ff"; 
rssfeed_title_color="#fff"; 
rssfeed_title_bgimage=""; 
rssfeed_footer="off"; 
rssfeed_footer_name="rss feed"; 
rssfeed_footer_bgcolor="#fff"; 
rssfeed_footer_color="#333"; 
rssfeed_footer_bgimage=""; 
rssfeed_item_title_length="50"; 
rssfeed_item_title_color="#666"; 
rssfeed_item_bgcolor="#fff"; 
rssfeed_item_bgimage=""; 
rssfeed_item_border_bottom="on"; 
rssfeed_item_source_icon="off"; 
rssfeed_item_date="off"; 
rssfeed_item_description="on"; 
rssfeed_item_description_length="120"; 
rssfeed_item_description_color="#666"; 
rssfeed_item_description_link_color="#333"; 
rssfeed_item_description_tag="off"; 
rssfeed_no_items="0"; 
rssfeed_cache = "f979e78f986cddbd6c6f6f2a13d5298a"; 
//--> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//feed.surfing-waves.com/js/rss-feed.js"></script> 
<!-- The link below helps keep this service FREE, and helps other people find the SW widget. Please be cool and keep it! Thanks. --> 
<div style="text-align:right; width:200px;">powered by <a href="http://www.surfing-waves.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank" style="color:#ccc;font-size:10px">Surfing Waves</a></div> 
<!-- end sw-rss-feed code -->
```

Comment: Utilizando esse widget você não tem forma de obter as imagens. Deverá implementar uma solução em JS para esse efeito. Recomendo jquery-rss: https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss

Comment: O seu XML da folha não tem imagens anexadas as noticias, logo não tem de onde puxar imagem alguma.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo essas imagens foram anexadas por causa do back-end PHP ?

Comment: as imagens já estão dentro das tags `<description> Bla bla bla <img .... /> mais bla bla bla </description>.` do rss que o php processa

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/rss_tag_image.asp

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo eu conseguir colocar uma imagem no fundo onde fica o titulo, mas não conseguir aumentar a altura do titulo, porque a imagem é grande, eu tentei adicionar essa tag "rssfeed_title_height=100"  mas não tive sucesso, será teria como me ajuda nesse sentido? só aumentar a altura do titulo.

Comment: O titulo que você se refere é a parte azul que está escrito InfoMoney : Câmbio

Comment: Esse widget não lhe dá muitas opções. O que você pode fazer e uma imagem do tamanho do quadro (200px de largura e 38px de altura postar no seu servidor e referenciar  em  `rssfeed_title_bgimage="http://seudominio.com/seusdiretorios/suaimagem.png";`  Veja esse exemplo feito sem muito esmero http://kithomepage.com/sos/rss-f.html